# Jquery draggable to sortable bug

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to drag elements to sortables container. It works ok, but sometimes there is a rebound effect. It's kind of random. I'm using jquery1.9.1 and jqueryui1.10.1.

The code is in here -> [http://jsfiddle.net/A7cPj/](http://jsfiddle.net/A7cPj/1/)

You can see a video of the bug here -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXUQRn7gnCc

Help me please!!!`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to see your bug in jsfiddle you provided when i switched `revert` to `false`. The bug seemed to not appear again.

```
 $("#draggableIconTextBlock").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable2, #sortable1",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "false"
});
```

and

```
 $("#draggableIconImage").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable2, #sortable1",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "false"
});
```